# What is causing blue screen and making my pc restart?

Tags: windows-7, memory, graphics-card, intel-core-i7, gaming

I need expert help. Recently a friend of mine brought spare parts and assembled a PC for me. The specs of the PC are as below :

```
Casing: Aerocool vs92 gaming
Processor: core i7 3.4-3.9GHz 8mb cache LGA1155
Mainboard: msi b75 MA-G43 professional
Memory: Kingston 4GB DDR3 1333
HARDDISK: TOSHIBA 500GB SATA 7200 RPM
GRAPHICS CARD: msi HD 6450 2GB FULL HD HDMI
WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE 64 bit
```

I have uploaded the minidump files on dropbox and posted the link below: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1i40f618m1kglc/Minidump.rar

Actually, the pc was rebooting with bccode error code 2b and a. After reinstalling the driver for graphics, now the computer is rebooting with error bccode 117, 1a, 4e, d1 and a.

Can someone please help me understand what is going on and how to solve this problem ? Should I change the graphic card? Is any part I should change to solve this problem ? I need expert help. please help me.

Comment: I suggest programs like BlueScreenViewer to better understand what drivers were loaded when the crash happened.  The first step would be to uninstall your display drivers, you don't indicate what version you had installed, uninstall them and see if the crash happens.

Comment: If you are getting random bluescreens that are different errors almost every time then it's most likely faulty RAM.  You need to start troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

The dumps show RAM issues (crash at nt!NtFreeVirtualMemory and nt!MiResolveDemandZeroFault):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck A, {fffffa86017ecff0, 2, 1, fffff80002ce835f}

Probably caused by : memory_corruption ( nt!MiReplenishPageSlist+100 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

2: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffffa86017ecff0, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000001, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80002ce835f, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!MiReplenishPageSlist+100
fffff800`02ce835f f00fba6b1000    lock bts dword ptr [rbx+10h],0

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  firefox.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiPageFault
nt!MiReplenishPageSlist
nt!MiRemoveAnyPage
nt!MiResolveDemandZeroFault
nt!MmAccessFault
nt!KiPageFault
0x0


IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_nt!MiReplenishPageSlist+100

*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000041790, A page table page has been corrupted. On a 64 bit OS, parameter 2
    contains the address of the PFN for the corrupted page table page.
    On a 32 bit OS, parameter 2 contains a pointer to the number of used
    PTEs, and parameter 3 contains the number of used PTEs.
Arg2: fffffa80047ebe10
Arg3: 000000000000ffff
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x1a_41790

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  dllhost.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
nt!NtFreeVirtualMemory
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
nt!KiServiceLinkage
nt!PspExitThread
nt!PspTerminateThreadByPointer
nt!NtTerminateThread
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
0x0


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x1a_41790_nt!_??_::FNODOBFM::_string_+339d6
```

Please download [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/download/5.01/), burn a new bootable CD (use a CD-RW if possible) from the ISO (download and use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download) to do this or make double click on the ISO in Windows 7), reboot your PC and scan your RAM 4-5hours for errors. If memtest86+ detects errors, test each module its own and replace the faulty RAM.

If the memtest tells no error, please download [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), look in the memory and SPD tab and verify that the current RAM Speed and the Timings match to the values that you see in the SPD tab. If your RAM run at CR (Command Rate) 1T, change the value into 2T in the BIOS.